# ASP Net "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

Faced with a very strange problem.
The program on the production server sends a get request to googleapis.
I get the error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

IIS 7

TLS 1.0/1.1./1.2, SSL 2.0/3.0 are enabled

.Net Framework 4.8

The URL "https://googleapi.com" added to the "Trusted sites" list

This URL opens in IE.
It works correctly on a working PC (and on all my others PCs) .
The problem is only on the production server.

Maybe someone has encountered something like this and will tell me where to find solution in this situation?

Test code:

```
string url = $"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine($"\n\n{result}\n\n");
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> Syste
m.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the r
emote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncReq
uest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncReq
uest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncReq
uest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRe
quest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object
state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, B
oolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at GoogleFetchTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Don't post your code as image, post it directly into your question

Comment: Does your site have the correct SSL certificate installed and binded?

Comment: you could try to use Wireshark https://www.wireshark.org/ or the network monitor tool to capture the network trace and see what is causing this issue.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 reached end of life for a very long time. Usually people do discuss about obsolete products like that and no one supports it any more. You will have to upgrade to a supported Windows version first. Note that on an obsolete Windows version, anything can happen so I don't think that's strange.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue related to protocols(TLS protocol). Using below solution before calling service should solve the issue,

**ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone!
I was helped by the inclusion of SSL 2.0 / 3.0 in the Internet options and adding the url "https://www.gogleapis.com" to trusted sites.

[Internet Option Sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKh7Y.png)